# XSL - How to obtain the unix environment variable

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to get the unparsed text and it will be stored in one of the unix directories whose path will change from one environment to the other. How can I obtain the base path dynamically using $ unix variables?

```
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="termcond">
<xsl:if test="($print_draft = '')">
  <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('/reports/generic_tc.txt','UTF-8')"/>
</xsl:if>
</fo:block>
```

I want to be able to pass the $PO_TOP unix variable to  (the below DOES NOT WORK)

```
 <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('$PO_TOP/reports/generic_tc.txt','UTF-8')"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd expect this is processor specific?

Comment: am not clear about your question on processor

Comment: There are a couple different xslt processors, and since accessing the environment variables is not part of xslt 2.0, each processor implementation has had to figure out if and how to support it. So which processor are you using?

Comment: What does the _(the below DOES NOT WORK)_ of your question refer to? Would you be willing to work with command line parameters passed to your XLST processor? If so, I could probably offer a solution to your question.

Comment: I actually had some syntax posted some how it is being trimmed away. What I meant was the reference to "dynamic location of the file using unix environment variables" I cannot work with a command line parameter as the xsl gets called dynamically from the ebusiness system. Also how do I find out which processor is being used?

Comment: Something like: select="unparsed-text('$PO_TOP/reports/generic_tc.txt','UTF-8')

Comment: It is probably almost impossible according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189689, then. This issue mentioned a way to extract the environment variables from a previously generated and stored file. Do you have access to the filesystem of the ebusiness system?